# How do I hide a div before the page is loaded?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a div on my page - I'd like when that page is being loaded that Div is being hidden by jQuery's .hide method. Now I have that when a page is ready then that div is hiding - but that hiding is visible. I don't want that

Now I have that code:

```
$(document).ready(function(event)
{            
   $('#Div1').hide('fast');
});
```

Comment: please be more clear... or give us some codes to debug... :)

Answer (score 3):

`.hide('fast')` will still animate. To do it (nearly) instantly use `.hide();`. However, you may still see a flicker, in which case what you want to do is append

```
style="display:none"
```

to the element in question as part of the initial html sent. This still allows you to use jQuery's `.show();` method later on if you wish.